# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно стоят запятые в предложении: «Сегодня олицетворением всевластия является «Единая Россия» и, похоже, что с этим все смирились»?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, знаки в предложении поставлены неправильно. Следует поставить запятые так: «Сегодня олицетворением всевластия является «...», и похоже, что с этим все смирились»? Здесь три простых предложения в составе сложного. Второе, **односоставное безличное с главным членом "похоже"**, к которому относится придаточное предложение "что с этим все смирились", не следует путать с вводным словом "похоже".

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что  слово "похоже" в данном случае должно быть вводным. Я бы убрала союз "что" и обособила слово "похоже".

Comment: Тогда,конечно,всё бы изменилось. Но автор не разрешает нам что-то убирать. Предложение построено правильно. Требуется только верно поставить знаки в нём.